# SOA domain records cannot be retrieved

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, nameserver, bind

I'm still having trouble setting up my nameservers. DNS check says the following about my nameserver address:

> Checking SOA records for domain. Domain server is not answering to UDP requests on port 53. Possible problems: A firewall is blocking port 53, server is down, server is not running software for handling dns requests.

I've run netstat -anp and found out that named is listening on tcp port 53, and it has udp port 53 on all IPs listed among active connections, **though I'm unsure if that also means the port is actually active.**

edit:
This problem is now solved. Everything was configured correctly, the problem was in zone files which didn't have appropriate permissions, so named couldn't read them.

Comment: Have you tried using `nslookup` from a remote computer to test your DNS server?

Comment: My registrar hasn't written the new nameservers into the DNS zone, because my server is not behaving like one (not answering the requests on UDP port 53).
If I run nslookup on my IP (the one that should act as ns1) I get a Non-Authoritative answer. There are however authoritative answers from two IP addresses that are close in range to mine, but I don't see how this could help me.

Comment: I'm thinking. Should I create a reverse lookup zone for my server's IP? The external one I mean, the one for localhost is already set up.

Comment: Since you found your own answer, you should post that as an answer and then mark it as accepted please.

Comment: I'd rather he accepted mine - it was the one that told him to go look in the BIND log file for the answer ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong.
The zone files had read permissions set only for root, so named couldn't open them.

Answer (score 0):

From here, I get answers from your servers for the two `.arpa` zones, but `SERVFAIL` for the `.si` domain.  Hence it's clearly not an IP stack or firewall problem.

Your BIND log file should tell you why that particular zone isn't working.  FWIW, I ran your `drustvo.zone` file against the `named-checkzone` program and it said there were no errors.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I found out what was the problem checking the logs when I restarted BIND. The zone files had read permissions set only for root, so named couldn't open them. Quite stupid, and to think I wasted a day o this...